# how to have a seamlessly pattern texture with equal scale in a object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, node-editor, procedural

how can i have a seamlessly pattern texture with equal scale in a object, i trying to make some procedural textures, but i have issues with the scale its not equal if i plug it to object or generated coordinates in this case i plug it in object (not uv because it creates seams) just like in the image showing there. [image]

Comment: what do you mean by "equal"? Also, as you have changed the Scale settings in the Mapping node, your texture will stretch on some axis..

Comment: by the way scale of object can affect texture display on it

Comment: @moonboots i want to all sides have that kind of brushed metal procedural texture, as you could see one side didnt.

Comment: As Ruben said, first of all, apply the scale of your object with a ctrl A. Now to create your texture you should use the Object output of a Texture Coordinate node, plug it into the Mapping node, and plug the Mapping into the Vector of your Noise (or Voronoi or Wave, whatever is your procedural texture). For the Mapping scale, keep the same value for both X, Y and Z, which is not the case in the screenshot.

Comment: @moonboots ok but i want for example the x axis more stretched like in the pic.

Comment: ah ok so maybe there's no solution except unwrapping and using Image Textures

Comment: i already unwrap it, and btw in the uv output creates seams, how can i avoid them?